# Visual Studio C++ : read access violation exception in Vector header

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm replicating the TextQuery example in C++ Primer 5th edition. The code compiles, but it keeps throwing "read access violation" from Vector header when a push_back operation is executed. Here's my code (* is the line with bug):

```
//main.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open("D:/OneDrive/Learning/C++/ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1/testfile.txt");
    runQueries(ifile); //*
// ...
}

//stdafx.h

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include "TextQuery.h"

//TextQuery.h
void runQueries(ifstream &infile)
{
    TextQuery tq(infile); //*
// ...
}

class TextQuery {
public:
    using line_no = std::vector<std::string>::size_type;
    TextQuery(std::ifstream&); //*
// ...
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> file;
    std::map < std::string, std::shared_ptr<std::set<line_no>>> wm;
};

TextQuery::TextQuery(std::ifstream &is)
{
    string text;
    while (getline(is, text)) {
        file->push_back(text); //*
    //...
    }
}
```

The next execution will raise an exception in vector header:

```
bool _Has_unused_capacity() const _NOEXCEPT
    {   // micro-optimization for capacity() != size()
    return (this->_Myend() != this->_Mylast());
    }
```

Here's the error message:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
std::_Vector_alloc<std::_Vec_base_types<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::allocator<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > >::_Myend(...) returned 0xC.
```

Here's the text file I used for testing:
    //text file
    text is good
    text is good
    text is good
    text is good
    text is good
    text is good
    text is good
    text is good
    text is good

Comment: It works initially. But the TextQuery didn't return desired result. So I tried to debug it. I don't know what I modified but this exception kept happening ever since, even after I reboot my PC.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], your question is off-topic without it. In particular, all the code after the bug happens can and should be removed. The separate class is also redundant.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt modified.

Comment: You forgot to allocate `file`. Why is it dynamically allocated at all?

Comment: @molbdnilo This solved my problem! I missed a part when I copied from the book: TextQuery::TextQuery(std::ifstream &is):file(new vector<string>)

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm just following the book. The explanation on the book is that this class shares data with another class. Because they need to synchronize the lifetime of shared objects, shared_ptr is used.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @molbdnilo: I forgot to allocate "file".

After changing the constructor to the following, the problem is solve:

```
TextQuery::TextQuery(std::ifstream &is):file(new vector<string>)
{
    string text;
    while (getline(is, text)) {
        file->push_back(text); //*
    //...
    }
}
```